# Display properties of the ListBox.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox, itemssource

I am new to WPF.  I have a ListBox that has its ItemSource set to a instance of [WorkItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemcollection%28VS.80%29.aspx).  (A collection of [WorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem%28VS.80%29.aspx) objects.)

When the list is displayed it only displays the type of each object (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem).  Is there a way to make the list display WorkItem.Title?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I will prob use both in the app I am doing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options.

The simplest method is to set the *[DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx)* property of your ListBox to "Title".

If you want to set not only what gets displayed, but the type of control that is used to display it, then you would set the ListBox's *ItemTemplate*.

For what your goal is, I would recommend the first option.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `DataTemplate` on the `ItemTemplate` property of the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="tfs:WorkItem">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <!-- Others -->
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That's a really complicated way of doing what DisplayMemberPath does in one line.

Comment: @Ray agreed, only use this if you're setting more complicated UI.