# ListBox showing "Namespace.Accounts" instead of actual text

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF ListBox - Display properties of the ItemSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659157/wpf-listbox-display-properties-of-the-itemsource)

I'm trying to implement a solution that will show items in a ListBox after adding them via a text box and Add button... Being new to WPF, I've almost got this figured out (after a week of banging my head against my desk...lol)

The problem is that the listbox is being populated with the "WinBudget.Accounts" instead of the actual item that is typed into the list box.

Please help.

**MODEL**

```
// the model is the basic design of an object containing properties
// and methods of that object. This is an account object.

public class Account : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_AccountName;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string AccountName
    {
       get { return m_AccountName;}
       set 
         { 
            m_AccountName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AccountName");
         }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
    }
}
```

**ListBox XAML**

```
 <ListBox Name="MyAccounts" />
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
// create a collection of accounts, then whenever the button is clicked,
//create a new account object and add to the collection.

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Account> AccountList = new ObservableCollection<Account>();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AccountList.Add(new Account{ AccountName = "My Account" });
        this.MyAccounts.ItemsSource = AccountList;
    }
     private void okBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       AccountList.Add(new Account{ AccountName = accountaddTextBox.Text});
    }
}
```

Comment: @lance, Referred to that thread. DisplayMemberPath = "AccountName" worked... thanks much!!

Answer (score 3):

WPF's UI can contain objects of any type, even classes such as `Account`. If the WPF encounters an object in the UI it doesn't understand, it will render it by using a `TextBlock` containing the `.ToString()` of the object.

In your case, the `ListBox.Item` is an `Account` object, so it is getting rendered with `Account.ToString()`, which returns the class name.

There are many different ways of handling this. My preferred method is usually to use a `DataTemplate`. This creates an application-wide template that tells WPF how to draw an object of a specific type.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Account}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Another method is to overwrite the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to specify what `ItemTemplate` to use for your `ListBox`. I would usually use this if I wanted to specify the template to use for this `ListBox` only

```
<ListBox Name="MyAccounts">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If your template is simple, such as the one shown, you could also set the ListBox's `DisplayMemberPath` which makes the default template look like the one shown above, with the binding pointing to whatever you put in `DisplayMemberPath`

```
<ListBox Name="MyAccounts" DisplayMemberPath="AccountName" />
```

And of course, you could also overwrite your `Account` object's `ToString()` method to return `AccountName` instead of the default ClassName, however I wouldn't recommend it in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `ListBox`'s item template display's the result of calling `ToString()` for an object. So you'll have to either override `Account.ToString()`, or provide a different template.

Comment: I prefer to use ToString() for displaying diagnostic information, not for UI needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make a binding to `Account::AccountName` property, but if you don't wnat or can't for any reason, quick and dirty solution could be

public class Account : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_AccountName;

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public string AccountName
{
   get { return m_AccountName;}
   set 
     { 
        m_AccountName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AccountName");
     }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}




   //NEW
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return AccountName;
   }

}
```